# Command line arguments: argv

Tags: c++

I would like to know why `argv` array can hold multi-character elements in the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  for (int nArg = 0; nArg < argc; nArg++)
  {
    cout << nArg << " " << argv[nArg] << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The code just prints out all arguments passed to the program.

When I run the program with arguments `foo`, and `bar`, `argv[1]` is `foo` and `argv[2]` is `bar`.

But `argv` is an array of `char`. And `foo` is not `char`, but a string. How can `argv[0]` be `foo`?

Comment: argv is array of char pointers which essentially are the way to express strings in C. I'd suggest to read a C book

Comment: `argv[0]` should be the program name or an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`argv` is actually a pointer, not an array. In both C and C++, a function parameter cannot be an array. If it looks like an array, it's quietly "adjusted" at compile time to be a pointer to the array's element type.

This:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

really means this:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

When your program is invoked, `argv` will be initialized to point to a `char*` object. That object is the initial element of an array of `char*` pointers, each of which points to (the initial element of) a *string* -- except that the final element, `argv[argc]` contains a null pointer.

`argv[0]` is a pointer to a string that represents the name of the program. If the program is invoked with two arguments, `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` will point to those arguments.

Finally, if you print a `char*` value using `std::cout << ...`, it will print, not the pointer value itself, but the value of the string that it points to.

> <strike>When I run the program with arguments `foo`, and `bar`, `argv[0]` is `foo` and `argv[1]` is `bar`.</strike>

<strike>Are you sure about that?</strike>  (Update: That was a typo in the question, now corrected.) If your program is named "my_program", the output of `my_program foo bar` should be something similar to:

```
0 my_program
1 foo
2 bar
```

Comment: That makes sense now. Thanks. As for the value of `argv[0]` and `argv[1]`, you are right-I had a typo in my question. Editing now.

Answer (score 1):

> But `argv` is an array of `char`.

Correction: it's an array of `char *`. `"foo"` is a `char *`, so this works.

An array of `char` is `char argv[]`.
An array of `char *` is `char *argv[]`. That's what you have.

Comment: Correction: `argv` is a pointer to a pointer to `char`. There are no array parameters in C or in C++; a declaration that looks like an array parameter is "adjusted" so it's really a pointer to the element type. `char *argv[]` really means `char **argv`. (There's a run-time requirement that the `char*` object that `argv` points to is the initial element of an array of `char*` objects, each of which points to a string.)

Answer (score 1):

> argv[0] is foo and argv[1] is bar ...

You should note that `argv[0]` always receives the actual program name called from the shell, so your command line arguments start from `argv[1]`.

You're just off by one.

Answer (score 0):

> But `argv` is an array of `char`.

It's not. It's an array of `char` pointers, and those pointers point to (zero-terminated) `char` arrays, i.e. C-style strings.

Technically, `argv` is not an array, but a pointer to an array (the array containing the `char` pointers). See Keith Thompson's comment on John Kugelman's answer for more details.

Comment: `argv` is a pointer, not an array; see my comment on John Kugelman's answer.