# Pointer and memory confusion in C

Tags: c, memory

If I have the following line of code:

```
int* a[3];
```

Does that mean it is a pointer to the first item in an array of 3 integers (thus, giving it a size of 4 bytes)? Or does it mean it is an array of 3 pointers (giving it a size of 12 bytes)?

Comment: Plug it into a C declaration->English translator: http://cdecl.org/

Comment: It is an array of 3 pointers to `int`: either way, don't guess the size, use `sizeof a`.

Comment: Why would an array of 3 pointers be 12 bytes? What guarantees that a pointer is 4 bytes? Why don't use use `sizeof a` and check that instead? If you are trying to learn then the important thing is the type of the variable `a` and it's size is not easily predictable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the type of command-line argument \`argv\` in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095850/what-is-the-type-of-command-line-argument-argv-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the `array of pointers to int` data type in `C` programming language. Therefore, each element of this array can hold an address of a variable of `int` data type.

```
 int x=5, y=9, z=8;
 int *a[3]; // Declare an array of pointers to int

 a[0] = &x;
 a[1] = &y;
 a[2] = &z;
```

However, the declaration like below will declare a pointer to an `array of 3 int`.

```
int (*a)[3];
```

Size of `a` is dependent on the platform for which you will compile your code. Please use `sizeof` operator for determining size in your platform.

```
 int *a[3];
 printf("Size of a: %zu\r\n", sizeof(a));
```

**NOTE:**

**To print result of sizeof operator, use %zu if your compiler supports C99; otherwise, or if you want maximum portability, the best way to print a size_t value is to convert it to unsigned long and use %lu. You can read about it over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943840/how-do-i-print-the-size-of-int-in-c).**

Answer (score 1):

In order to understand expressions and declarations you must know the operator precedences. There are plenty online, for example [here.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

On that page you can see that angle brackets have a higher priority than the dereferencing asterisk, which means that they are applied first. If you like you can bracket parts of the declaration with parentheses, just like in an expression:

```
int *(a[10]); // brackets are redundant and show operator precedence
```

Therefore, the variable `a` must be an array. The array *element* resulting from the indexing yields, after the dereferencing operator is applied, an `int`, so that the element must be a pointer to int.

Thus, the declaration declares an array of int pointers.

As an extra, you cannot declare a pointer to an array without parentheses or typedefs, just because the operator precedences are made for the much more common case above. A pointer to an array would look like this:

```
int (*a)[10]; // brackets are necessary to make "*" apply first
```

Here, the dereferencing asterisk is applied first; `a` therefore must be a pointer. The resulting type can be indexed, therefore must be an array, whose elements are declared `int`s. This makes `a` a pointer to an array of `int`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can test this yourself with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
        int *a[3];
        printf("%zu\n", sizeof(a));
        return 0;
}
```

The output is 12, which, on the machine I'm testing it on, and apparently yours too from what you wrote in your question, is `3*sizeof(int)`.

[Type declaration precedence](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) in C puts the "array" declaration `[]` one step above the "pointer to" declaration (`*`), so the declaration is:

```
Declare 'a' as an array of 3 pointers to type 'int'
```

You can use parentheses (`()`) to change the order in which the type declaration is processed:

```
int (*a)[3];
```

`sizeof(a)` gives it an output of 4, which on your machine is the size of a pointer.

As a side note, it's generally bad practice to assume that a pointer is always 4 bytes and that an `int` is always 4 bytes.  This varies depending on architecture, compiler, CPU mode, etc.

Comment: Use `"%zu"`, not `"%d"`, for `size_t` values.